# php two equaL columns from text in text file to image

Tags: php, image, text

```
<?php
//include new data
//require_once 'grab.php';

$filename = "result.txt";

function convert($path) {
    $lines = file($path);
    $newpath = substr($path, 0, -3) . 'png';
    $im = imagecreate(800, 20 * count($lines));
    //background//
    $red = imagecolorallocate($im, 178, 34, 34);
    //background//
    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    //background//
    //$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    
            
        foreach($lines as $i => $line) {
        //unknown-leftMargin-lineSpace//
        imagestring($im, 12, 50, 20 * $i, trim($line), $white);
        
    }
    imagepng($im, $newpath);
    imagedestroy($im);
}

//chdir('C:\TOP-20');
convert($filename);
echo "<center><img src='result.png' height='auto' width='auto' alt='error'><br>";
?>
```

**I can only produce a single column in an image how do i create two equal columns like 10 on teh left and 10 on the right. **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this ?

```
<?php
//
//include new data
//require_once 'grab.php';

//$filename = "result.txt";
$filename = "result.txt";

function convert($path) {
    $lines = file($path);

    $width = 800;
    $n = count($lines);
    $nhalf = ceil(count($lines)/2.0);
    
    $newpath = substr($path, 0, -3) . 'png';
    $im = imagecreate($width, 20 * $nhalf);
    //background//
    $red = imagecolorallocate($im, 178, 34, 34);
    //background//
    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    //background//
    //$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    
    $x = 50;
    $j = 0;
    
    foreach($lines as $i => $line) {
        //unknown-leftMargin-lineSpace//
        imagestring($im, 12, $x, 20 * $j, trim($line), $white);
        $j++;
        if($j == $nhalf) {
            $x = $width - 200;
            $j = 0;
        }
        
    }
    imagepng($im, $newpath);
    imagedestroy($im);
  
    return $newpath;
}

//chdir('C:\TOP-20');
$newpath = convert($filename);
echo "<center><img src='$newpath' height='auto' width='auto' alt='error'><br>";
?>
```

It produces an image

[image]

Comment: Now to improve upon calling a font style and size with padding around the image.